# collection1: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unknown fieldtype 'text' specified on field Report_Name

Tags: xml, solr

I am following the tutorial as in http://www.sunilgulabani.com/2013/01/import-mysql-database-with-apache-solr.html. I have modified the **data-config.xml** as :-

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource driver="sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver" type="JdbcDataSource"
       url="jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=" + "C:\\users\\ppreeti\\executive_db.accdb" user="" password="" />
    <document name="products">
       <entity name="Report" query="select * from Report">
           <field column="Report_Name" name="Report_Name" />
           <field column="Report_ID" name="Report_ID" />
           <field column="Section_ID" name="Section_ID" />
           <field column="Contact_ID" name="Contact_ID" />
           <field column="ZipFile_IND" name="ZipFile_IND" />
           <field column="Last_Update" name="Last_Update" />
           <field column="Link" name="Link" />
           <field column="link_id" name="link_id" />
           <!--<entity name="Contact" query="select Contact_Name from Contact where item_id='${item.ID}'">
               <field name="features" column="description" />
           </entity>
           <entity name="item_category" query="select CATEGORY_ID from item_category where item_id='${item.ID}'">
               <entity name="category" query="select description from category where id = '${item_category.CATEGORY_ID}'">
                   <field column="description" name="cat" />
               </entity>
           </entity>-->
       </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

I have also not followed the step 4 as mentioned in the tutorial since I am accessing MS Access database and I found out that it is inbuilt .

I've also modified **schema.xml** following another tutorial by **adding** the following lines before the  tag:-

```
<fields>

    <field name="Report_Name" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
    <field name="Report_ID" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
    <field name="Section_ID" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
    <field name="Contact_ID" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
    <field name="ZipFile_IND" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
    <field name="Last_Update" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
    <field name="Link" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
    <field name="link_id" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>


    <dynamicField name="*" type="ignored" />
 </fields>

 <uniqueKey>Report_ID</uniqueKey>
 <!-- field for the QueryParser to use when an explicit fieldname is absent -->
 <defaultSearchField>Report_Name</defaultSearchField>
```

So,when I run on browser as described in step-5 , I get the error as:-
**collection1: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unknown fieldtype 'text' specified on field Report_Name**

So, how should I resolve the error ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no longer a fieldType of `text` defined in the default solrconfig.xml file anymore.  Try changing all the fields in your schema.xml file to use `type="text_general"` as this is a suitable replacement found in the current solrconfig.xml file.

I would also recommend that you look at the solrconfig.xml file in your installation as well as reading the [Analyzers, Tokenizers, and Token Filters](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters) page on the Solr Wiki to better understand how the fieldType definitions are setup.